# Apply FFT on BufferedImage give me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, image-processing, java-8, fft, bufferedimage

I create a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) and try to apply [FFT algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Java) from rosetta code on the [`DataBufferInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBufferInt.html) generated by the `Robot` but it's fail in the fft method and I don't know why.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10,200,200);
BufferedImage capture = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
// All data in getDataBuffer() seems to be negative
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)buffer.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Complex[] cinput = new Complex[pixels.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    cinput[i] = new Complex(pixels[i], 0.0);
}
// Fail (method from rosetta code)
FastFourierTransform.fft(cinput);
```

Give me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 40000
at engine.FastFourierTransform.fft(FastFourierTransform.java:42)
at engine.ImageProcessing.FFT(ImageProcessing.java:30)
at test.Testor.main(Testor.java:24)
```

I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: The code of the FFT implementation looks like the array length must be a power of two.

Comment: @Holger, Effectivelly, when I hardcode the size of `cinput` by a power of two, it doesn't crash, I will do bigger test after the week-end, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Note that other language versions on the linked site even have a comment about this restriction.

Comment: The Rosetta code uses the iterative version of the classic Cooley-Tukey algorithm, so it's always limited to powers of 2. Bluestein's [chirp-z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform) would be the general way to solve this. You can find a Java implementation [here](https://www.nayuki.io/page/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Catalano Framework](https://github.com/DiegoCatalano/Catalano-Framework), you can easily perform the fast fourier transform. Also works for MxN-sized images.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10,200,200);
BufferedImage capture = r.createScreenCapture(rect);

FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(capture);
fb.toGrayscale();

FourierTransform ft = new FourierTransform(fb);
ft.Forward();
fb = ft.toFastBitmap();

//Display the image
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fb.toIcon());
```

Comment: Thank you, even if I prefer avoid framework, your solution is working fine ;) it was to retrieve the position of a subimage from a complete image.